# Dynamically set folium zoom and postion to geopandas dataframe extent

Tags: geopandas, folium

I have a geopandas dataframe containing many polygons.

I wish to plot these in a folium map and have that map set the zoom and extent dynamically to fit all polygons onto the map.

I've tried the following

```py
bounds = df.total_bounds
m.fit_bounds(bounds)
m
```

But get `TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:-

```
m.fit_bounds([[bounds[0],bounds[1]], [bounds[2],bounds[3]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it returns the same error.

Comment: @mappingdom Then please post your JSON data object, and also the `df` dataframe, with your runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simpler and more readable:

```
bounds = df.total_bounds.tolist()
m.fit_bounds([bounds[:2][::-1], bounds[2:][::-1]])
m
```